# Best Practice automated MongoDb Cluster Restart

Tags: windows, mongodb

We have a MongoDB cluster and would like to restart all members of a cluster.

We could automate the windows services to restart or use `shutdownServer` via mognoshell.

But we don't want to have the database unavailable, so an idea would be to only restart the slaves, make a step down, then restart the old master.

I know I can determine masters and slaves with `rs.status()` and with `rs.StepDown()` and `rs.freeze()` I can manage who the primary is.

But is there an built in way to restart a MongoDB cluister without downtime? Or would I have to write a tool which reads the status of the server and then handles this manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "safe restart" mechanism build in mongo yet.

To solve that,  custom tool will have to follow those steps:

- Take list of servers (A, B, C)
- Check if A is primary -> if not restart and wait x minutes
- -> if yes put it at the end of list

....

- when we reach last server - issue stepdown, wait for finish and restart

When stepdown is issued - all clients are forcibly disconnected from master, but reconnection will be made to new master immediately.

Comment: ok thx thats the way i would do the tool : )  jsut wanted to make sure to not reinvent the wheel